# Loop over data object Vuejs to create a menu

Tags: arrays, loops, vue.js

I am looking for creating a menu by iterating on a nested object in the data object of Vuejs.

Here is the loop I have thought of:

```
<ul v-for="category in categories" :key="category">  {{ category }}
  <li v-for="subCategory in category" :key="subCategory">
    <router-link to="/"> {{ subCategory }} </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It would a simple menu with a one level of nested sub-menus.

```
categories: [{
  Atoms: ['Buttons', 'Icons'],
  Molecules: [],
  Organisms: [],
  Templates: [],
  Utilities: ['Grid']
}]
```

It is a component, so with the data: function(){}.

I know it is an easy problem but I don't manage to get a clean list with the menus (Atoms, Molecules...) as the ul, and the sub-menus (string in each array) as the li.
Right now, I get the all array on the screen, with the [] and {}.

And I don't why Vuejs, when I look in Chrome console, adds some '0' objects between each layer of data.

Thanks for your help.
I tried to make a JSfiddle but it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is let `categories` be an object :

```js
categories: {
  Atoms: ["Buttons", "Icons"],
  Molecules: [],
  Organisms: [],
  Templates: [],
  Utilities: ["Grid"]
}
```

And then use `Object.entries(categories)`. This will transform the object into a 2 dimensional array where you can access both the name and the values while looping over it.

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories: {
      Atoms: ['Buttons', 'Icons'],
      Molecules: [],
      Organisms: [],
      Templates: [],
      Utilities: ['Grid']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="[ category, subCategories ] in Object.entries(categories)" :key="category">
    {{category}}
    <li v-for="subCategory in subCategories" :key="subCategory">
      <div> {{ subCategory }} </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`[ category, subCategories ] in Object.entries(categories)` here I am using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to directly decompose the object into to separate variable.

Comment: It works, thanks.
But is there any solution by just organizing correctly the data object?

Comment: Well you could organise `categories` like that : 

`categories : [ { name : "Atoms",  subCategories : ["Buttons", "Icons"] } ]`